# Unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts c# at specific location

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I have an Windows application developed in `WPF` which connects to `MySQL` database using `MySQL Connector`.

Application in my local computer and other computers, works perfectly. But when I try to Install and Run the application in Gulf country, it gives below error message:

> unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts c#

I have disabled `Firewall`, `AntiVirus` but still issue is not getting resolved. I want to know what could be the issue ?

There are many questions posted in `StackOverflow` but non of them helped me.

Comment: Check if you can `ping` the mysql server.  Try to create a connection to your MySql using Visual Studio Server Explorer

Comment: Which device do you use Gulf? Some home router device has option for client isolate function. So client cannot access each other.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: I have checked everything. On my local machine it works perfectly.

Comment: @mkysoft: it is windows 10. 64-Bit OS

Comment: Check again or check in a new pc. Setup and share a mysql is almost straight forward. So unless you have the firewall blocking the request should work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: I have checked the same in another machine of same country. There also same problem arise.MySQL is hosted on a server. So connection could not be a problem. There is something which is preventing database to be connected.

Comment: Which host name do you use for mysql server address? If you are using localhost, may be it is resolve ipv6. Mysql some versions not working with ipv6 by default. Close ipv6 support on windows network device settings and re-try.